# Imported module prints out None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not sure if anyone asked this already but I could not find was I was looking for, so here we go.
I have created a module named xxx.py. This is whats inside:

```
class A(object):
     def aaa(self):
        print "Ahaaaa!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```

Also I have another script ex45.py:

```
from xxx import A

xxx = A()
print xxx.aaa()
```

When I run python ex45.py I get the following:

```
PS E:\python\ex\ex45> python ex45.py
Ahaaaa!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
None
```

Why is there that 'None'???

My purpouse is to write multipe scripts where I create classes that I want to use in another script. I am sure there are better ways to code but I am now learning python and I want to understand how everything works.

P.S.: I am using python 2.7.9. and learning from the book Learn Python the hard way.

Comment: Because your print will print the return of the method. You are not returning anything explicitly, so by default the method will return `None`. Try it again with a return of `return 42` and see what happens.

Comment: It is the *output of `aaa()`*. Since `aaa()` does not return anything explicitly, it returns `None` implictly.

Comment: I have tried with return 42 and instead of None I get 42.
Is there a way to get id of the return value and rint out only 'Ahaaaa!!!!!'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your `aaa()` method returns `None`. Sou you print out something and then you also print out the returned value. Try this:

```
from xxx import A

xxx = A()
xxx.aaa()
```

And this (one at time):

```
class A(object):
     def aaa(self):
         return "Ahaaaa!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```

And see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The `aaa` method prints out `"Ahaaaa!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"` and returns nothing (in Python what doesn't return anything actually returns `None`). Then, in `ex45.py` you print the return value of `aaa`, which is `None`.

To solve the problem, you may either do `xxx.aaa()` (without `print`ing), or in the `aaa` method return `"Ahaaaa!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"` instead of `print`ing it.